# Why does lower frequency require a lower voltage to drive a logic value?

Tags: frequency, low-power

> Dynamic frequency scaling almost always appear in conjunction with dynamic voltage scaling, since lower frequencies require lower voltages for the digital circuit to yield correct results. The combined topic is known as dynamic voltage and frequency scaling (DVFS)

The quote above is from the [Wikipedia article for DVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling) (note that the article has since been edited, in response to this question, so this is *not* identical to the passage in the current article). It says that lower frequencies require lower voltages for digital circuit to yield correct results. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: I'm a little suspicious about that being correct.

Comment: I think whoever wrote that committed the fallacy of affirming the antecedent. It is true that higher speeds require higher voltages. Now here comes the fallacy: "Therefore lower speeds require lower voltages." It might be true to say that maximizing power savings requires lowering both the voltage and the speed because of V^2 * C * F.

Comment: The English in that statement is clumsy, to the point of being wrong. It's necessary to have a high voltage for high speed. It is necessary to reduce the speed if you reduce the voltage. A low voltage is sufficient for operation if you reduce the speed.

Comment: @kuba-hasnt-forgotten-monica  Your edit doesn't help this question. We have to keep the old version to make question/answer/comments understandable.

Comment: Since the Wikipedia article has also been update it is _extra_ important that the original words are preserved here. The question obviously makes no sense if the new edit is transferred here.

Comment: @pipe You are entirely correct about the need to preserve the *original* quote that prompted your question, not quote the new article. However images of text is a pretty terrible way to quote something, so I don't believe rolling back the edit was a good move. I submitted an edit that *both* converts it to proper text marked-up as a quote (with a link for citation) and keeps the original quote you were asking about.

Comment: @Ben I did not ask about anything.

Comment: @pipe Apologies, I must have mistaken the "last edited" user block for the author one, again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There Wikipedia article is wrong (I fixed that mis-statement), and in general is very badly written.

Lower frequencies *allow* lower voltages -- they do not *require* a lower voltage. Conversely, higher frequencies *require* higher voltages for the logic to operate properly.

So, if there is little computation to be performed, it can be more efficient to slow the clock, and execute the clock cycles using a lower supply voltage.

Comment: This is my understanding too. That lower frequencies *allow* for lower voltages while higher frequencies *require* higher voltages.

Comment: Can you please explain how lower frequencies allow lower voltages? Is it because a lower frequency allows for more time for a capacitor to charge or discharge based on pre-charge and evaluate phases, thus allowing us to use lower voltages? (since a lower voltage would mean more charging and discharging time)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *for a given CMOS technology* a lower gate voltage means a higher channel resistance when the transistor is on.  This means that the RC time constant for the channel resistance and the transistor's load is longer.  That would mean that you'd have to slow down the clock rate to get reliable operation.  (Or, conversely, slowing down the clock would allow lower voltages, for the same reason).

Comment: @penguin99 yeah at high frequency and low voltage, the processor will have timing errors because the lower voltage makes the logic chain propagation times slower. The required result can't make it to the flip flop before the clock. When the voltage is increased, the propagation delays become shorter and the timing is OK.

Comment: The sentence construction is ambiguous, not wrong.  The requirement is a lower speed circuit is weaker, the minimum voltage it requires is lower, and that is a valid reading of the sentence.  Unfortunately your reading as "the maximum voltage it allows is lower", a stronger requirement, is also a valid reading of the sentence.  Put another way, there is a required voltage, which is a threshold dividing allowed from non-allowed values.  No matter whether one talks about allowed, unallowed, or required, the change is downward.

Comment: It's nice to correct the misunderstanding that lower frequencies don't *require* the voltage to be lower (whether or not the article-writer or the OP had that misunderstanding, some readers might). But higher frequencies do require higher voltages, so there is still a difference to be explained, and I think a better answer would explain that difference.

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic power loss is:

Pd = V^2 * C * F

where Pd is dynamic power, V is voltage, C is process capacitance, and F is frequency.

There is also some dynamic power loss due to switching, but I guess I don't want to get into that.

In order to run error free at any given speed, a certain minimum voltage must be maintained. As the clock speed is increased, the required minimum voltage also increases.

So power loss will be minimized if the processor always adjusts the voltage to the minimum required for correct operation. This means that in order to maintain low dynamic power consumption, the processor (or system) must lower voltage when it lowers the clock speed.

However, apart from wasting power, there is no harm done if the voltage is maintained at the "high speed" voltage level. It just means power loss is not minimized.

I hope this clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does lower frequency require a lower voltage to drive a logic value?

**It doesn't.

Lowering both f and Vdd simply saves more power.**

- CMOS consists on 2 complementary MOSFET switches which have an RdsOn and Coss values which dissipate power for each gate that switches voltage states for 0 & 1.
- Each switch transition draws a certain amount of energy thus is proportional to **2f**
- The RdsOn and thus slew rate reduces with lower supply voltage.
- The FET output capacitance Coss stored energy draws power, Pd during rise time T defined by  \$P_d=½  ~C_{oss}V_{dd}^2\$ that depends on Vdd thus relative power consumption varies with number of gates , N toggling on average with each clock transition and frequency.

$$P_d=N f C V^2$$ .

- Overclocking (OC) the CPU often demands that the supply be raised to reduce RdsOn.
- Thus the power saving software for CPU's can reduce Vdd when reducing the clock rate according to the same timing margin for maximum power savings.
- The thresholds of % CPU are set in the Control Panel Power Management for minimum and maximum savings such as 100% and 5% use.

Comment: I think OP is asking about the quote's implication that the voltage *must* go down with frequency. I am a little skeptical as to whether the quote is correct. My understanding is that voltage *can* go down with frequency but not that it must.

Comment: I agree and somewhat implied it must go down somewhat to maintain the same margin. But certainly can and does slow down much more. My 3.1GHz i7 Xeon CPU goes  to 0.775GHz and drops voltage 25% and normally operates <1 % CPU on W7 x64 or 10%cpu at 775 MHz watching a TV series on the web with Stremio.

Comment: timing margin depends on supply voltage and latency. Frequency control depends on usage and margin. But latency does dictate a minimal frequency reduction to maintain margin but that dies not guarantee adequate mobile battery or tower power savings.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a SWAG, hopefully somebody else comes along that can explain this much better. DVFS mainly depends on the required circuit speed differences.  This is generally done in highly complex chips such as computer ICs. You will find in many CPUs the core runs much faster then the memory and other surrounding logic. One of the things they do to compensate for this is add cache memory. This is faster memory that is closely coupled to the CPU and runs faster then system memory or additional caches but is usually slower then the core. As technology has progressed the memory has gotten faster and the voltage is lower. Not so long ago memory chips were 5V.

These interfaces generally also are at different voltages causing interfacing problems.  The output ports (pins) will generally have the highest voltage while the core generally has the lowest. The reason the faster it is running the more current it takes to charge and discharge the internal capacitance. Decreasing the size of the gates and voltage reduces the heat and helps it operate faster. This current consumption is dissipated as heat. To compensate for this they decrease the size of the silicon and lower the voltage. This can be seen on the high performance CPU chips. Heatsinks help get rid of some of this heat.

Many CPUs actually operate at many different frequencies and voltages concurrently. Generally but not always the farther you get from the core the slower the logic will operate and the higher the voltage. When two different units operating at different voltages get together,usually on the same die, you will also encounter what is known as transition overhead which can be generated when voltage and frequency are scaling (either direction) because of the extra circuitry. This is far from complete, there are books published on this. Hopefully this gives the basics you need to start to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

In very simplified terms, the transistors in modern CPU's turn on or off by charging or discharging a capacitor. The electric field imposed by the capacitor (the gate) opens or closes the channel between the source and drain. In order to charge that capacitor to a given voltage needed to open or close the gate, there's a minimum number of literal electrons (counted in coulombs) you have to push in there. If there were no resistance at all, you could get infinitely high (and infinitely short) pulses of current to charge and discharge the capacitor, but that's not realistic, so in order to increase the gate current (in order to charge it faster) you increase the voltage.

On the side of designing transistors, you can also work to reduce the capacitance of the gate so fewer coulombs of electrons (less total current) are needed to switch the transistor. Additionally it is beneficial to reduce the resistance between the power supply and the gate so a lower voltage drives a higher current. Once you have the circuit in-hand however, about the only thing you can do is to bump the voltage..